# i m trying to avoid duplicate product code in opportuinity line item but its not updating

Tags: apex, duplicate-management, duplicate-value

```
trigger duplicatecode on OpportunityLineItem (before insert) {
{
    Set<String> setProductCode= new Set<String>();
    For(OpportunityLineItem nam : trigger.new)
    {
        setProductCode.add(nam.ProductCode);
    }
   if(setProductCode.size() > 0 )
    {
       List<OpportunityLineItem> oppo = [select productcode,id from OpportunityLineItem where ProductCode in :setProductCode ];

        Map<String ,OpportunityLineItem> mapNameWiseoppo = new Map<String,OpportunityLineItem>();
        For(OpportunityLineItem nam : oppo)
        {
            mapNameWiseoppo.put(nam.ProductCode ,nam);
        }
        For(OpportunityLineItem nam : trigger.new)
        {
            if(mapNameWiseoppo.containsKey(nam.ProductCode))
            {    
                nam.Name.addError('code already Exist ');    
            }    
        }    
    }    
}    
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "its not updating"?

Comment: its not showing error whenever i add duplicate product code

Comment: The **OpportunityLineItems** are not the same... are they? You are looking same Product Codes but the OpportunityLineITem are probably not the same. Your logic should be different I think. You should use the OpportunityLineItem Id as key value in your map and Product Code as values.

Comment: i should avoid duplicate product code in opportunityline items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **OpportunityLineItems** are not the same... are they?

You are looking same Product Codes but the **OpportunityLineITem** are probably not the same. Your logic should be different I think. You should use the **OpportunityLineItem** Id as key value in your map and Product Code as values.

Try to invert them and change the map. Something in this line.

```
Map<Id, String> mapNameWiseoppo = new Map<Id, String>(); 

for(OpportunityLineItem nam : oppo)
        {
            mapNameWiseoppo.put(nam.Id, nam.ProductCode);
        }
```

It think it is better to use the Id in your map and then use the `containsKey()` to look for the **ProducCode**.

As mentioned in my last commend, this is a **before insert** only, so update DML operations will not fire this trigger. If you want to catch updated records change your trigger declaration to:

```
trigger duplicatecode on OpportunityLineItem (before insert. before update)
```

Try this:

```
trigger duplicatecode on OpportunityLineItem (before insert, before update) 
{

 Map<String, OpportunityLineItem > OppLineItemMap = 
              new Map<String, OpportunityLineItem >();

for (OpportunityLineItem oppLineItem: System.Trigger.new)
{

// We want to target those new OpportunityLineItems with a Product Code and 
// compare them with OpportunityLineItem already in the system

if ((oppLineItem.ProductCode !=null) &&
       (System.Trigger.isInsert ||
         (oppLineItem.ProductCode != 
           System.Trigger.oldMap.get(oppLineItem.Id).ProductCode )))
{

//Firing error if we find a OpportunityLineItem already with same Product Code 

if (OppLineItemMap.containsKey(oppLineItem.ProductCode))
{
    oppLineItem.ProductCode.addError('code already Exist.');
    //If not found, we add the lead to our leadMap
    }else{
      OppLineItemMap.put(oppLineItem.ProductCode, oppLineItem);
    }
  }
}
//We query our OpportunityLineItem and use the ProductCode as the 
// reference. If found on our map, throw an error 
   for (OpportunityLineItem oppLiIt: 
            [SELECT ProductCode 
                 FROM OpportunityLineItem
                     WHERE ProductCode IN :OppLineItemMap.KeySet()])
 {

  OpportunityLineItem newOpopLiIT = OppLineItemMap.get(oppLiIt.ProductCode);

 // Error needs to be on the field that is causing it, in this case,
 // the ProductCode  field 

   newOpopLiIT.ProductCode.addError('An Opportunity Line Item with this 
     Product Code already exists.');
  }
}
```

Didn't tested but something like this should work... You can see a similar approach in **[my bloq](http://ccloudonline.nl/?p=878)**:

********  **UPDATE** ************

Try on the **Product2** object and not on the **OpportunityLineItem**.
Create a trigger on the Product2 standard object and paste this.

```
trigger duplicatecodeProduct on Product2  (before insert, before update) 
{

 Map<String, Product2 > Product2Map = 
              new Map<String, Product2 >();

for (Product2 Product2Item: System.Trigger.new)
{

// We want to target those new Product2 with a Product Code and 
// compare them with Product2 already in the system

if ((Product2Item.ProductCode !=null) &&
       (System.Trigger.isInsert ||
         (Product2Item.ProductCode != 
           System.Trigger.oldMap.get(Product2Item.Id).ProductCode )))
{

//Firing error if we find a Product2 already with same Product Code 

if (Product2Map.containsKey(Product2Item.ProductCode))
{
    Product2Item.ProductCode.addError('code already Exist.');
    //If not found, we add the lead to our leadMap
    }else{
      Product2Map.put(Product2Item.ProductCode, Product2Item);
    }
  }
}
//We query our Product2 and use the ProductCode as the 
// reference. If found on our map, throw an error 
   for (Product2 Product2LiIt: 
            [SELECT ProductCode 
                 FROM Product2
                     WHERE ProductCode IN :Product2Map.KeySet()])
 {

  Product2 newProduct2 = Product2Map.get(Product2LiIt.ProductCode);

 // Error needs to be on the field that is causing it, in this case,
 // the ProductCode  field 

   newProduct2.ProductCode.addError('An Opportunity Line Item with this Product Code already exists.');
  }
}
```

Tested on the Product2 object and it works:

Trying to update a record that already have the **ProductCode** throws error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: product code should not save with duplicate value

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. But you can use the OpportunityLineItem as the key and in there is any OpportunityLineITem with the same Product Code the error should fired. Your trigger is on **before insert** only, so make sure that you are aware of the fact that **updating** a record will not fire this trigger.

Comment: can u help with the code

Comment: @raj try the code on my answer.

Comment: productcode in if statement is showing error

Comment: try now, I have make changes to the code

Comment: code is not working

Comment: Try the new one on the Product2 object... that should work.

Comment: ok... good to know..